# How to use -replace twice in one statement in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the -replace function in Powershell twice, but the only way I can accomplish this is using the following code:

```
$data = Get-Content c:\test.txt
$data -replace 'A','apple' | Out-File c:\newtest.txt
$data = Get-Content c:\newtest.txt
$data -replace 'B','blue' | Out-File c:\newtest2.txt
```

I believe there should be a way that I can consolidate line 2 and 4 so that I can use only newtest.txt vs having my correct output in newtest2.txt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use brackets:

```
((Get-Content c:\test.txt) -replace 'A','apple') -replace 'B','blue' | Out-File c:\newtest2.txt
```

---

Or you could this, if you prefer. There's no reason why you can't use the `-replace` operator twice.

```
$data = Get-Content c:\test.txt
$data -replace 'A','apple' -replace "B","Blue" | Out-File c:\newtest.txt
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! I had tried to put | between the -replace, thx

Answer (score 0):

There is a replace method available for strings as well which can be use multiple times.

We only need to use the replace operator when we use regular expressions

```
(Get-Content c:\test.txt).replace('A','apple').replace('B','blue') | Out-File c:\newtest2.txt

$data = Get-Content c:\test.txt
$data.replace('A','apple').replace("B","Blue") | Out-File c:\newtest.txt
```